# Appending multidimensional array to form data

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Ok I'm trying to append data to an existing form when someone submits it.

```
function submitCustOpts() {
var custoptsids=new Array(".implode(",",$optids).");
var pfrm=document.forms['promotion".$promo_data["promo_id"]."'];

for(var i in custoptsids) {
    selectedVal = $('#'+custoptsids[i]).val();

    var input = $('<input>').attr(
    {
        type: 'hidden',
        name: 'cf_'+custoptsids[i],
        value: selectedVal
    }).appendTo(pfrm);
}
pfrm.submit();
}
```

EVERYTHING works. So just ignore the first half. The part I can not get it the appending to the form.
The custoptsids[i] holds the id and the selectedVal holds the value. It's all working dandy, but I need to put this in a multidimensional array.
Right now it submits like this:

```
<!-- REQUEST: Array
(
    [promo_id] => 164792
    [station_id] => 2478
    [lang] => en
    [cf_28] => 55
    [cf_29] => 61
    [PHPSESSID] => 375ee178f5de3blahblahblah
)
-->
```

When it should look like this:

```
<!-- REQUEST: Array
(
    [promo_id] => 164792
    [station_id] => 2478
    [lang] => en
    [cf] => Array
        (
            [28] => 55
            [29] => 60
        )

    [PHPSESSID] => 375ee178f5de3blahblahblah
)
-->
```

So my question is how do I put those values into the cf array.. cf_28 should be just cf with 28 and 29 as the array keys for the inner array..

Comment: Maybe i'm missing somehing, but shouldn't "name: 'cf_'+custoptsids[i]" be instead "name: 'cf['+custoptsids[i]+']'"?

Comment: Omg... You are the BEST!!!!!!! Thank you! I can't believe I overlooked that. I guess that's what you get for programming for 9 straight hours x_x

Comment: Do you want to go ahead and answer it and I'll mark you answer correct? =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm happy to help, also if you were really a step from the "solution". 
The solution would be "pause for a while", "have a coffee/tea", go back to code. But anyway:

```
var input = $('<input>').attr(
{
    type: 'hidden',
    // name: 'cf_'+custoptsids[i], <- look twice :)
    name: 'cf['+custoptsids[i]+']',
    value: selectedVal
}).appendTo(pfrm);
```

Its the same for me. EVERY time. Glad I could help.

Comment: Thank you again <333 Yeah I haven't taken my lunch yet, but I'm eating now =) I never seem to take breaks until I get it working, but I should try and do that more often :P